# Are there Specific ways to add a build to a TestFlight internal group

Tags: testflight

I Submitted my application to the Itunes Connect Service to use TestFlight for internal testing, I have 2 Testers invited that have accepted however nothing is showing up on the test-flight app

And when I go to the testers on test-flights I just see that "No Builds Available"

Am I missing a step? Submit Say no To Encryption Warning , Add Testers.

[Review or no Review Same Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FJnf.png)

[image]

Comment: Looks like some issue on Apple's end. Having the exact same issue. Use the "Contact Us" link at the bottom of the Apple Store Connect page.

Comment: I had the exact issue as-well I ended up just submitting for external testing